# Taillwind plugins (tailwind-scrollbar-hide) are not working in remix.js

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, remix.run

I have this plugin installed. tailwind-scrollbar-hide.

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

export default {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        staat: ["Staatliches", "Inter"],
      },
      width: {
        "right-col": `calc(100% - 75% - 48px - 8px)`,
      },
      height: {
        "main-area": `calc(100vh - 48px)`,
      },
    },
    plugins: [require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide")],
  },
} satisfies Config;
```

and used it like this

```
<div className="scrollbar-hide ml-2 w-full flex-col overflow-auto">
    <div className="mb-2 h-1/2 w-full rounded-lg bg-white"></div>
    <div className="mb-2 h-1/2 w-full rounded-lg bg-white"></div>
</div>
```

But the corresponding css does not appear in the browser.

I tried other plugins and seems something with the plugins because none of them are working.

Already reinstaled remix.

Can any one help me understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plugins array should not be nested within the Theme object.

Update your config to the following and it should work.

```json
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

export default {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        staat: ["Staatliches", "Inter"],
      },
      width: {
        "right-col": `calc(100% - 75% - 48px - 8px)`,
      },
      height: {
        "main-area": `calc(100vh - 48px)`,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide")],
} satisfies Config;
```